# Initialize SDK with licence programmatically

Tags: android, here-api

In here SDK 3.4 release note, we can read: "Applications can now dynamically initialize the HERE Android SDK with a license key rather than hard
coding the license key in the application's Android manifest file."

This is a nice addition, but I can't find documentation. The current doc regarding authentication is only presenting the old manifest.xml way (https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/credentials.html)

Can you point me out to some relevant documentation?

Comment: I don't understand the minus votes. Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an [ApplicationContext](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-common-applicationcontext.html#topic-apiref) object to set the appid, appcode and permission key. After that, use the new [MapEngine#init(ApplicationContext, OnEngineInitListener)](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-common-mapengine.html#topic-apiref__init-applicationcontext-onengineinitlistener) instead.

Comment: Thank you. I initialized the engine using MapFragment#init(appContext, listener) instead.